# Is it possible to refer to a parameter passed to a method within the passed block in ruby?

Tags: ruby, block

I hope I am not repeating anyone here, but I have been searching google and here and not coming up with anything. This question is really more a matter of "sexifying" my code.

What I am specifically trying to do is this:

```
Dir.new('some_directory').each do |file|
  # is there a way to refer to the string 'some_directory' via a method or variable?
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in general; it's totally up to the method itself what arguments the block gets called with, and by the time `each` has been called (which calls your block), the fact that the string `'some_directory'` was passed to `Dir.new` has been long forgotten, i.e. they're quite separate things.

You can do something like this, though:

```
Dir.new(my_dir = 'some_directory').each do |file|
    puts "#{my_dir} contains #{file}"
end
```

Comment: Oooo, I like that!  I wasn't even aware that was legal.  I'm still a ruby n00b.  Sorry I can't up-vote y'all, I got no reputation yet.

Comment: ie, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I was just trying to save myself ONE line of code and this is it :)

Comment: :)! It's a good way to make things compact, but like most good things, overuse will lead to unreadable code, so I tend to use it sparingly or where it makes sense. (I think it makes sense here.)

Comment: And it definitely is legal; nearly everything you'd consider a "statement" in another language (i.e. belongs at the top level) is an expression in Ruby (can go anywhere a value like `"hello"` or `(4 + 4)`), so for instance, `Dir.new(my_dir = if something == 'blah'; 'something or other'; else; 'what!?'; end).each …` is equally syntactically valid!

Comment: Ah yes, I certainly have heard this, but being a plain ol' "web developer" (as opposed to a "computer scientist") coming from PHP, the power and uses for this have not always been so obvious. Also, thanks for the welcome! Too bad one of my introductory comments spelled "new" as "knew". Can't win 'em all.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it won't work is that `new` and `each` are two different methods so they don't have access to each others' parameters. To 'sexify' your code, you could consider creating a new method to contain the two method calls and pass the repeated parameter to that:

```
def do_something(dir)
  Dir.new(dir).each do |file|
    # use dir in some way
  end
end
```

The fact that creating a new method has such a low overhead means it's entirely reasonable to create one for as small a chunk of code as this - and is one of the many reasons that make Ruby such a pleasure of a language to work with.

Comment: Cool; I was afraid of that.  I know I can just assign 'some_directory' to a variable but I was trying to save myself one whole line :)  Thanks!

Comment: Whoa, obviously I am knew here, but when I responded the first time it was only showing the first line of your answer.  People respond so quickly here!  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Just break it out into a variable. Ruby blocks are closures so they will have access -

```
dir = 'some_directory'
Dir.new(dir).each do |file|
  # use dir here as expected.
end
```